# How to get a list of vertices from a list of edges in bmesh?

Tags: python, bmesh

So if I have a list of edges,

```
selected_edges = [e for e in bm.edges if e.select]
```

How would I make an array of the vertices contained in the edges of that list?

For context: in my project I'm making a list of shared vertices between two lists of edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Use sets.**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

Will most likely be duplicates in the following vertex list, from any connected edges.

```
selected_verts = [v for e in bm.edges if e.select for v in e.verts]
```

Converting to `set(...)` will have only one member for each vertex.

```
 set(selected_verts)
```

or defining as set in first place.

```
selected_verts = {v for e in bm.edges if e.select for v in e.verts}
```

The [`set(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) sounds like the way go as you can check intersection between sets of vertices easily.

between sets.